# Почему не присуждается знак «Любознательный» («Curious»)

Tags: обсуждение

Несколько дней назад прогресс знака **«Любознательный»** (**«Curious»**) был заполнен полностью (даже немного больше, чем нужно):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопросы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Репутация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на профиль](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5275890/denis-bubnov)

Условия: *«Задавайте интересные вопросы в течение 5 разных дней и поддерживайте положительный баланс голосов»* - соблюдены.

В связи с этим возник вопрос, почему данный знак не был присужден? Я думал, что система просто через некоторое время сделает это, но уже прошло порядка нескольких дней - а знака все нет.

Данный знак должен быть получен на англоязычной версии сайта «[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)», но я думаю, что система работает одинаково и для русской и для англоязычной версий сайтов.

Comment: Капитан Очевидность подсказывает, что под цифрой 6/5 стоит крест на условии "требуется положительный баланс голосов".

Comment: Хм. Посмотрел [профиль](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5275890/denis-bubnov?tab=questions). Такое впечатление, что единички в ответах не считаются за "положительное" число. Например, я получил бейдж за пять вопросов: за два вопроса с оценкой "+2", два вопроса с оценкой "+3" и один вопрос с оценкой "+4". Бейдж получил в полночь, при расчёте. Поскольку я вопросы почти не задаю, то это было наглядно видно, что рубеж переполз.

Comment: @AK, странно, не правда ли? **«+1»** - это не положительное число :)

Comment: Вообще, слова "positive" и "положительный" имеют не только смысл "положительный" (больше нуля), но и (бинго!) смысл "позитивный" (одобрительный). Возможно, что позитивный использовалось именно в смысле одобрительный и тогда вам нужны "+2" и выше в ответах?

Comment: Вероятно, у вас нет вопросов с отрицательным балансом голосов, закрытых вроде бы тоже нет, но вероятно есть удалённые.  Если какой-то вопрос был заминусован и закрыт, а потом вы его удалили, он посчитается трижды. Возможно такое?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, по видимому да. Странно, что удаленные тоже считаются :)

Comment: @DenisBubnov задавать и удалять вопросы - это не тот формат участия, который ожидается и одобряется. Например вот этот весьма неплохой вопрос был, если акцентировать внимание на оптимизации, а не просто перечислять способы. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/526675/181472

Comment: Не поймите меня неправильно. Во-первых, вам никто не может запретить удалить вопрос (пока на него нет заплюсованных ответов). Во-вторых, конечно бывают вопросы, которые не принесут большой пользы и если их удаляет автор - это хорошо. Например те, которые вызваны опечатками. Или совсем уж оффтопик. Но геймификация сайта работает для всех одинаково, поэтому в общем и целом она поощряет ситуацию, когда вопрос публикуется и не удаляется. Для исключений в формуле есть запас - сравнение с 0,5 а не 0,99 каким-нибудь.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, понимаете в чем дело, да этот вопрос можно было не удалять, но почему-то мой вопрос рассмотрели как глупый или что-то в этом роде. Я ожидал получить пару ответов с возможными примерами, а получил кучу комментариев. Что касается удаления вопросов - в самом начале были проблемы и с формулированием вопросов и с форматированием. Нашел на анг SO вопрос, с плохим рейтингом, который я удалил.

Comment: @DenisBubnov ну если такой вопрос один, то это -2 или если он ещё и закрыт был, то -3. В общем-то не критично на общем фоне, пара хороших вопросов повернут баланс в вашу сторону. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо Вам за разъяснения. У меня правда еще один маленький вопрос: "Как быть с вопросами, на которые никто не ответил, либо которые просто заминусовали"? Если я сам понял, что написал глупость - я удаляю это сам, но ведь это как-то портит статистику. Поясните пожалуйста.

Comment: @DenisBubnov вот тут какая-то дыра в системе. Если вопрос действительно неудачный и его заминусовали, то его обычно стоит удалить самостоятельно. И тут геймификация идёт вразрез со здравым смыслом, т.к. рейтинг это немного ухудшит. Но заминусованный вопрос без ответов всё равно рано или поздно удалит Дух сообщества (Community), так что он в любом случае будет удалён. Так что рекомендую плюнуть на статистику. У вас же на ru.SO есть удалённые вопросы, но это не помешало получить знак.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо за советы и пояснения.